# How to pick 100 items fairly out of a list of x

Tags: loops, math, graph

So the situation I face is this:

I'm rendering a graph, but each entry I add to it decreases the load time. I want the graph to use a maximum of 100 entries, but the amount of entries I have is variable.

So lets say I have 500 entries available for this graph. Only 100 of them should be added to the graph, distributed evenly (so e1, e6, e11, e16 ... e496). If i have less entries than 100, it should use the entries I have.

So:

```
500 -> 100
150 -> 100
50 -> 50
10 -> 10
```

What formula/loop should I use to determine which entries are selected for the graph?

Answer (score 0):

This should either do the job or at least give you a head start:

```
fun reduce(List list, int maxLen) : List {

    int skip = list.length > maxLen ? list.length / maxLen : 1;

    List r = new list();

    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i+=skip){
       r.add( list[i] )
    }

    return r;
}
```

List listOf100 = reduce( aBigList, 100 );